# How to install Cypress prerequisites and Chrome on Amazon Linux 2 v5 (or AL2023)?

Tags: google-chrome, cypress, amazon-linux-2, amazon-linux-extras, amazon-linux-2023

It appears that Amazon Linux 2 v5.0 image (`Amazon Linux 2 x86_64 standard:5.0` [runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html) available to CodeBuild) no longer contains Amazon Linux Extras, which makes a lot of documentation and answers about installing Chromium or Chrome obsolete.

I was looking to install prerequisites for Cypress, including a browser since AL2 no longer comes with any.

`yum` would fail with an error like this:

```
$ yum install chromium
No match for argument: chromium
Error: Unable to find a match: chromium
```

Same thing happened with `gtk2-devel` and `GConf2` we used with the previous versions of AL2.

Answer (score 1):

I found [a solution for Amazon Linux 2023](https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/discussions/417) (AL2023) which worked for AL2 v5.0 image as well. Note it installs Chrome and not Chromium:

```
$ export BROWSERS_SRC_DIR="/usr/src/browsers" && mkdir -p $BROWSERS_SRC_DIR
$ curl https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm \
    --output $BROWSERS_SRC_DIR/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
$ yum install -y -q $BROWSERS_SRC_DIR/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

Additionally, here is the list of dependencies I installed for Cypress before this. It does not match the exact list from [Cypress AL2023 documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#Linux-Prerequisites) so it's possible some things can be removed:

```
yum install -y xorg-x11-server-Xvfb gtk3-devel libnotify-devel nss libXScrnSaver alsa-lib
```

(AL2v5 logs indicate that `xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`, `nss` and `alsa-lib` are present in the image already so they most likely can be skipped)